# Change the makefile all target place in the file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I've got a big makefile with all and phony target, now I want to change the place of it in the file i.e., not in the begin of the file

this is working

```
all: tdir execute build run

tdir:
   @mkdir -p "$(DIR)"
   DIR  := $(CURDIR)

m := $(shell ftr build)
m := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(m)))
execute:
 echo test
```

if I change the place of the all like this its not working

```
tdir:
   @mkdir -p "$(DIR)"
   DIR  := $(CURDIR)

m := $(shell ftr build)
m := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(m)))

all: tdir execute build run
execute:
 echo test
```

I know that I’ve `tdir` before the all, does Make provide a solution for this kind of issue?
let's assume that I want to move the `all` to bottom

Comment: "_Not working_" is not a clear description of your problem. If you want `all` to be the default goal (that is the goal used when invoking make without specifying goals on the command line), please state it clearly in your question (and have a look at the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` make special variable in [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)).

Answer (score 1):

If you run `make` passing no targets on the commandline then by default
it makes the first target in the makefile. From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals)

> 9.2 Arguments to Specify the Goals
>
> ...
>
> By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting targets that start with a period).
>   Therefore, makefiles are usually written so that the first target is for compiling the entire program or programs they describe.
>
> ...
>
> You can manage the selection of the default goal from within your makefile using the .DEFAULT_GOAL variable (see Other Special Variables).

The authors of makefiles usually call the first (default) target `all`,
but not always. Sometimes it is called `default`, or something else. Make
attaches no special meaning to `all`.

As the manual says, you can explicitly choose the default target by setting the special `.DEFAULT_GOAL` variable. So

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

tdir:
    ...


all: tdir execute build run
    ...
```

will behave in the way you want. But without `.DEFAULT_GOAL := all`, the
default target is `tdir`, and if you wish to make `all` then you must specify
that target on the commandline:

```
$ make all
```

`.DEFAULT_GOAL` is rarely used. Normally, people write the default target first
in the makefile, and call it `all`.